# PHPExcel : Data validation not working in .xls format

Tags: php, oop, phpexcel

I have a excel file with two sheet:

1. **Worksheet**;
2. **List**- list of items which will display in `Worksheet` sheet as a list item.

Please see the below images:

[image: List]   [image: Worksheet]

I want to generate this using **`PHPExcel`** library. I have tried but not getting the expected results. See my below code :

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Soumya Biswas")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Soumya Biswas")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");


// Create a first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A5', "List");


// Set data validation
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B5')->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
$objValidation->setFormula1('"$List.$A$1:$A$10"');  // Make sure to put the list items between " and "  !!!

$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List');

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A{$i}", "List Item {$i}");
}
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);




header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="data-validation.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the correct syntax for referencing ranges of cells in another sheet is:

```
List!$A$1:$A$10
```

So you should try:

```
$objValidation->setFormula1('List!$A$1:$A$10'); // tested it, worked for me
```

Got the idea from http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/320393:

> ->setFormula1("Worksheet!A1:{$endCell}1");// work....

Although this guy had another problem with using named ranges.

Background: I think with:

```
$objValidation->setFormula1('"$List.$A$1:$A$10"');
```

you're explicity using the given string between the quotation marks as the list value as explained here: [here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/441114) (where you probably got this snippet in the first place) or [here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/447270).
But since you don't want to use fixed list items but dynamically referred ones, you should omit the double quotation marks.

Comment: $objValidation->setFormula1('List!$A$1:$A$10');  this works but if I write a value which is not in the list it prompts the error then if you click in the accept button it will put the wrong value in the cell, how can I prevent this? UPDATE: use $objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_STOP);