# How to force evaluate the PHP Excel Validation for formula

Tags: php, excel-formula, phpexcel

I tried the following code on setting the validation for PhpExcel

```
const VALIDATION = '"=Sheet3!$B$2:$B$21"';

$objValidation = $activeSheet->getCell($cellAddress)->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);

$objValidation->setFormula1(self::VALIDATION);
```

However, when I open the excel generated, the dropdown shows the string **=Sheet3!$B$2:$B$21** not a list of value from the evaluated ranges.

Is there any work around here?

Comment: Perhaps this may help you? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718546/phpexcel-data-validation-not-working-in-xls-format what's the format of your output file? Excel2007? Anyway, try removing the brackets from your constant validation, maybe setFormula1 is just parsing the string instead of interpreting it: const VALIDATION = '=Sheet3!$B$2:$B$21';

Comment: this will just the value of VALIDATION in your select option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're quoting the data validation formula as a string (with the double quotes), so it's being interpreted as a string.

A quoted string will be treated as a comma-separated list of entries, which is why `'"Item A,Item B,Item C"'` will be treated as a list of `Item A`, `Item B` and `Item C`.

For a formula, use

```
const VALIDATION = '=Sheet3!$B$2:$B$21';
```